# Create proportion of each variable by panel variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset where I have the primary ID and wave along with a flag for each type (within a wave). It looks something like this.

```
| id | wave | TypeA | TypeB | TypeC |
|----|------|-------|-------|-------|
| 1  | 1    | 1     | 0     | 0     |
| 2  | 1    | 0     | 0     | 1     |
| 3  | 1    | 0     | 1     | 0     |
| 4  | 1    | 1     | 0     | 0     |
| 5  | 1    | 0     | 1     | 0     |
| 1  | 2    | 1     | 0     | 0     |
| 2  | 2    | 1     | 0     | 0     |
| 3  | 2    | 0     | 0     | 1     |
| 4  | 2    | 1     | 0     | 0     |
| 5  | 2    | 0     | 1     | 0     |
| 6  | 2    | 0     | 0     | 1     |
```

I would like to create a new column for each type that holds the proportion of each type of individual in a wave. Each wave doesn't have the same number of individuals. The output should look like this:

```
| id | wave | TypeA | TypeB | TypeC | TypeA_prop | TypeB_prop | TypeC_prop |
|----|------|-------|-------|-------|------------|------------|------------|
| 1  | 1    | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0.4        | 0.4        | 0.1        |
| 2  | 1    | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0.4        | 0.4        | 0.1        |
| 3  | 1    | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0.4        | 0.4        | 0.1        |
| 4  | 1    | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0.4        | 0.4        | 0.1        |
| 5  | 1    | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0.4        | 0.4        | 0.1        |
| 1  | 2    | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0.5        | 0.17       | 0.33       |
| 2  | 2    | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0.5        | 0.17       | 0.33       |
| 3  | 2    | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0.5        | 0.17       | 0.33       |
| 4  | 2    | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0.5        | 0.17       | 0.33       |
| 5  | 2    | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0.5        | 0.17       | 0.33       |
| 6  | 2    | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0.5        | 0.17       | 0.33       |
```

I don't usually use R with panel data so I'm new to this. How can I go about this (preferably with dplyr)? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have binary (1/0) values in `Type` column you can take `mean` of columns for each `wave`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(wave) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('Type'), mean, .names = '{col}_prop')) %>%
  ungroup

#      id  wave TypeA TypeB TypeC TypeA_prop TypeB_prop TypeC_prop
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1     0     0        0.4      0.4        0.2  
# 2     2     1     0     0     1        0.4      0.4        0.2  
# 3     3     1     0     1     0        0.4      0.4        0.2  
# 4     4     1     1     0     0        0.4      0.4        0.2  
# 5     5     1     0     1     0        0.4      0.4        0.2  
# 6     1     2     1     0     0        0.5      0.167      0.333
# 7     2     2     1     0     0        0.5      0.167      0.333
# 8     3     2     0     0     1        0.5      0.167      0.333
# 9     4     2     1     0     0        0.5      0.167      0.333
#10     5     2     0     1     0        0.5      0.167      0.333
#11     6     2     0     0     1        0.5      0.167      0.333
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L), wave = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), TypeA = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), TypeB = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), TypeC = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -c(id, wave)) %>% 
   group_by(wave) %>% 
   mutate(tot = sum(value)) %>% 
   group_by(wave, name) %>% mutate(type_tot = sum(value)) %>% 
   mutate(prop = type_tot/tot) %>% 
   select(id, wave, name, value,prop) %>% 
   pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id,wave), names_from = name, values_from = c(value,prop))
# A tibble: 11 x 8
# Groups:   wave [2]
      id  wave value_TypeA value_TypeB value_TypeC prop_TypeA prop_TypeB prop_TypeC
   <int> <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1     1           1           0           0        0.4      0.4        0.2  
 2     2     1           0           0           1        0.4      0.4        0.2  
 3     3     1           0           1           0        0.4      0.4        0.2  
 4     4     1           1           0           0        0.4      0.4        0.2  
 5     5     1           0           1           0        0.4      0.4        0.2  
 6     1     2           1           0           0        0.5      0.167      0.333
 7     2     2           1           0           0        0.5      0.167      0.333
 8     3     2           0           0           1        0.5      0.167      0.333
 9     4     2           1           0           0        0.5      0.167      0.333
10     5     2           0           1           0        0.5      0.167      0.333
11     6     2           0           0           1        0.5      0.167      0.333
```

Data used:

```
df
   id wave TypeA TypeB TypeC
1   1    1     1     0     0
2   2    1     0     0     1
3   3    1     0     1     0
4   4    1     1     0     0
5   5    1     0     1     0
6   1    2     1     0     0
7   2    2     1     0     0
8   3    2     0     0     1
9   4    2     1     0     0
10  5    2     0     1     0
11  6    2     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

using **data.table**

```r
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
                            6L), wave = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), TypeA = c(1L, 
                                                                                                 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), TypeB = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), TypeC = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
library(data.table)
cols_select <- grep("^Type", names(df), value = T)
nm_prop <- paste0(cols_select, "_prop")
setDT(df)
out <- df[, (nm_prop) := lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = T), by = wave, .SDcols = cols_select]
head(out)
#>    id wave TypeA TypeB TypeC TypeA_prop TypeB_prop TypeC_prop
#> 1:  1    1     1     0     0        0.4  0.4000000  0.2000000
#> 2:  2    1     0     0     1        0.4  0.4000000  0.2000000
#> 3:  3    1     0     1     0        0.4  0.4000000  0.2000000
#> 4:  4    1     1     0     0        0.4  0.4000000  0.2000000
#> 5:  5    1     0     1     0        0.4  0.4000000  0.2000000
#> 6:  1    2     1     0     0        0.5  0.1666667  0.3333333
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>